# Chest X Ray Image Generation using GAN

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I am new to GAN and using it to generate more Chest X Ray Images but I am facing problem to save that generated images as a individual image not  in the form grid.[GAN Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueEoB.png)

So how can I save all the generated images as individual images
The code that I am using to saved it in the form of grid is given below

```
def sample_images(epoch):
  rows, cols = 10, 10
  noise = np.random.randn(rows * cols, latent_dim)
  imgs = generator.predict(noise)

  # Rescale images 0 - 1
  imgs = 0.5 * imgs + 0.5

  fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
  idx = 0
  for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
      axs[i,j].imshow(imgs[idx].reshape(H, W), cmap='gray')
      axs[i,j].axis('off')
      idx += 1

  fig.savefig("normal_gan_images/%d.png" % epoch)
  plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fig` in `fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols)` represents the whole subplot. So you're saving the whole grid as the result.

So, try this:

```
def sample_images(epoch):
  rows, cols = 10, 10
  noise = np.random.randn(rows * cols, latent_dim)
  imgs = generator.predict(noise)

  # Rescale images 0 - 1
  imgs = 0.5 * imgs + 0.5

  for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
      plt.imshow(imgs[i])
      plt.savefig(f"normal_gan_images/{epoch}_{i}.png")
      plt.close()
```

Comment: I am running the same code as provided by you but getting the below error TypeError: Invalid shape (22500,) for image data

Comment: Oh. What is the shape of `imgs` ?